# D3.js : is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I faced two problems while using d3.js but they raise the same error.
The first one when I want to use that piece of code with one of my array :

```
/**
 * Simple JS equivalent of the Python set() constructor (without the      methods)
 * @requires shim: Array.prototype.indexOf
 * @param {array} arr The array to turn into a set
 * @example
 * var mySet = set(['red', 'yellow', 'black', 'yellow']);
 * mySet.length; // 3
 * JSON.stringify(mySet); // ["red","yellow","black"]
 * @see For a fuller version, see {@link https://npmjs.org/package/set}
 */
function set (arr) {
   return arr.reduce(function (a, val) {
      if (a.indexOf(val) === -1) {
        a.push(val);
}
return a;
    }, []);
 }
```

D3.js raise : arr.reduce is not a function.
The same error appear when I try to use

```
.attrTween('fill',function(d,a){
                            //choose color dynamicly      
                            return d3.interpolate(a,colorCalibration[zscale(d[2])]);
                             })
```

to fill a rectangle. It said attrTween is not a function. Here is more of code :

```
 var zscale = d3.scale.quantize()
                     .domain([0,200])
                     .range([0,1,2,3,4,5]);
 var colorCalibration =    ['#f6faaa','#FEE08B','#FDAE61','#F46D43','#D53E4F','#9E0142'];
```

Comment: which version of jquery you are using ? can you try with the latest jquery?

Comment: I work in a JSfiddle. I tried with the latest version : `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js" integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` but it doesn't work

Comment: Why are we talking about `jquery` versions here?  `.reduce` is an ECMA5 language feature.  What browser are you using?  It should be supported natively in IE9+ and in Chrome going back to almost the beginning of time...

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: @Mark I doubt that this is caused by a missing implementation of `.reduce()`, much more likely is `arr` not an array. Which brings me to the main point: I only see the implementation of function `set()`, but there is no hint at how and where it is actually used. What parameter is passed in to argument `arr`?

Comment: @altocumulus, good point.